# How to name data frame in for loops using object?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have an object that contains list of lab tests and based on the length of the object, I have created a FOR loop that processes scripts. During each loop, R should create a data frame using list in that object. Please see below.

```
adlb <- data.frame(subjid = c(1:20), aval = c(100:119))
adlb$paramcd <- ifelse(adlb$subjid <= 10, "ALT", "AST")
lab_list <- unique(filter(adlb, !is.na(aval))$paramcd)
for (i in 1:length(lab_list))
{
  lab_name <- unlist(lab_list)[[i]]
  print(lab_name)`

  **???** <- adlb %>% 
  dplyr::filter(paramcd == lab_name) %>% 
  drop_na(aval) 
}
```

When I run it, it should first create data frame named ALT followed by AST. What should I replace ??? with?
Only reason why I would prefer it this way is because it helps me to review data in question and debug scripts when needed.

Thank you in advance.

I tried lab_name[[i]] and few other options but it resulted in either error or incorrect data frame name.

Comment: You can use `assign()`, for example `assign(paste(lab_name, i, sep=""), unlist(lab_list)[[i]])` in your `for` loop

Comment: you can also just put the dataframes into a list as you were sort of attempting with lab_name[[i]]. Just assign an empty list ```lab_name<- list()``` before the for loop.

Comment: @megmac Thanks for the response but after updating script on my end as you suggested, it does NOT create data frame in global environment. Instead it creates lab_name list. I was kind of hoping for actual data frames named ALT & AST. No matter what I do, it doesn't give what I want :(

Comment: you can turn list into dataframes  ```list2env(mylist ,.GlobalEnv)``` I cannot run your code as it throws errors at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:

```
# example dataframes
df1 <- iris
df2 <- mtcars
df3 <- iris
#put them into list
mylist <- list(df1,df2,df3)
#give names to list 
names(mylist) <- c("df_name1","df_name2","df_name3")

#put dataframes into global env
list2env(mylist ,.GlobalEnv)
```